# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson" but have it in build path on local project on Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gson

I'm attempting my first Java project and would like to use Gson to read in a Json file (which I generated from a spreadsheet) to then be added as class objects.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Init {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("Log_Model.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
         Object json = gson.fromJson(fr, Item[].class);
         //https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects
         System.out.println(json);
        }
```

When I run this I get the following error,

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at relog.Init.main(Init.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm using Eclipse which is installed in my User folder on Windows 7, the gson jar is placed in the project folder and I've added it to the build path.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're running into a conflict between the classpath and the modulepath, which was introduced in Java 9 and is the source of more headaches than all the rock concerts ever performed. I very strongly recommend using Maven or Gradle, perhaps with a very simple project generated by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) (you can just ignore all the Spring parts for now and run stuff out of `main`, but it gives you a working project structure).

Answer (score -1):

Adding GSON to project :

> Open **Windows** >**preferences** in the Eclipse menu, and navigate to the
> **Java** >**Build path** > **User Libraries** tab. Click **new** and enter a new User
> **Library name**: like “gson_lib” and hit ok. With “gson_lib” selected
> press **Add External JARs** and find the **gson-2.8.6.jar** you downloaded.
> Apply and Close.

First create class JSON Schema. You can make class structure with [JsonToSchema](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
Example :

```
public class User {
    
    public String name, email;
    public int age;
    
    public User(String name, String email, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
}
```

Code :

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;

public class Main {
private static final Type USER_TYPE = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("user.json"));       
    // change the JSON string to Object
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<User> data = gson.fromJson(reader, USER_TYPE); // contains the whole user list
    data.toScreen(); // prints to screen some values
    }    
}
```